# Remove item from Firefox context menu

Tags: firefox, context-menu, search-engines

With new version 89 of Firefox,
when you are in some webpages,
(I noticed it on YouTube and Mozilla Support)
appears a new item when you right-click on the address bar

screenshot below: [image]
you can notice *Add "Mozilla Support"* as last item in the context menu.

**Question is: how can I remove it?**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the *Add "Mozilla Support"* registers Mozilla Support as a Search Engine in the list of available search engines that Firefox has registered for you.
To remove it in FF.v91 , go to your Settings > Search page (url is `about:preferences#search`). In the "Search Shortcuts" section, you'll see any addresses you've accidentally added. Highlight the entry to remove and click the "Remove" button.